# Difficult limit of expression involving logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms, substitution

I'm trying to calculate the limit

$$ L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left (\ln^2(n)\ln \left (\frac{\ln(\frac{n}{t})}{\ln(\frac{n}{t+1})}\right )-\ln(n)\ln \left (1+\frac{1}{t} \right) \right),$$
where $t$ is a fixed positive integer, but have so far been unsuccessful. I have reason to suspect that 
$$L=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left (1+\frac{1}{t}\right )\ln \Big(t(t+1) \Big)=\frac{1}{2} \Big(\ln^2(t+1)-\ln^2(t) \Big) \hspace{15mm} (\ast)$$ because (1). Wolfram alpha sais so (without providing any step by step solution ) and (2). It seems to be correct numerically.

Let $$F(n):=\ln^2(n)\ln \left (\frac{\ln(\frac{n}{t})}{\ln(\frac{n}{t+1})}\right )-\ln(n)\ln \left (1+\frac{1}{t} \right).$$
For simplicity, we may take $n=e^m$, so that 
$$F^*(m)=m^2\ln \left (\frac{m-\ln(t)}{m-\ln(t+1)}\right )-m\ln \left (1+\frac{1}{t} \right)$$
and 
\begin{equation}\exp(F^*)=\frac{\left(\frac{m-\ln(t)}{m-\ln(t+1)} \right )^{m^2}}{(1+\frac{1}{t})^{m}}= \left(\frac{t}{t+1} \right )^m\left(\frac{m-\ln(t)}{m-\ln(t+1)} \right )^{m^2}\end{equation}
I do not know how to calculate the limit of this as $m \to \infty$. One could substitute $a=\frac{t}{t+1}$ and then set $b=\ln(a)$. The result is (any of) these expression: 
$$a^{m} \left (1+\frac{\ln(a)}{x-\ln(t/a)} \right )^{m^2} =e^{bm} \left(1+\frac{b}{x+b-\ln(t)}\right )^{m^2}=e^{bm} \left(1+\frac{b}{x-\ln(t+1)}\right )^{m^2}.$$ If we pick, say the rightmost expression above and take the logarithm, the problem is reduced to calculating the limit $$\lim \limits_{m \to \infty} \left(bm+m^2\ln \left (1+\frac{b}{m-\ln \left( t+1 \right ) } \right ) \right )$$
$$=\lim \limits_{m \to \infty} m\left(b+\ln \left (\left[1+\frac{b}{m-\ln \left( t+1 \right ) } \right )\right]^{m} \right)$$
$$=\lim \limits_{m \to \infty} m \left( b+ \ln \left ( \left[ 1+\frac{b}{m-\ln(t+1) } \right]^{m-\ln(t+1)} \left[ 1+\frac{b}{m-\ln(t+1) } \right]^{\ln(t+1)} \right) \right)$$
which does at least have the appearance of a simpler problem. Then, setting $m=\ln(t+1)+x$ we must calculate the limit of
$$\Big(\ln(t+1)+x\Big) \left(b+\ln \left(\left[1+\frac{b}{x} \right]^{x} \right)+\ln(t+1)\ln \left(1+\frac{b}{x} \right ) \right)$$
as $x$ goes to infinity. (The plan in this calculation is to use $e^b=\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+b/x)^x$) as some point. I have also tried to calculate the limit $(\ast)$ using L'Hopitals rule, but to no avail. Does anyone see the golden step i am missing ? : )

Comment: $$
\texttt{Limit[Log[n]^2*Log[Log[n/t]/Log[n/(t + 1)]] - Log[n]*Log[1 + 1/t], 
 n -> \[Infinity]]}
$$

$$
\left(i \text{sgn}\left(2 \pi  \left\lfloor \frac{\arg (t)+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor -2 \pi  \left\lfloor \frac{\arg (t+1)+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor +i \left(\log \left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)+\log (t)-\log (t+1)\right)\right)\right) \infty.
$$

I don't think this has a nice closed form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a=\ln(t)$, $b=\ln(t+1)$ and $x=1/\ln(n)$. Then $x\to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$ and
$$\ln^2(n)\ln \left (\frac{\ln(\frac{n}{t})}{\ln(\frac{n}{t+1})}\right )-\ln(n)\ln \left (1+\frac{1}{t} \right)=\frac{\ln(1-ax)-\ln(1-bx)-(b-a)x}{x^2}.$$
Now by using the Taylor series 
$$\ln(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+O(y^3),$$
we find that the above LHS is
$$\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}+O(x).$$
Therefore the limit $L$ is equal to
$$\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}=\frac{\ln^2(t+1)-\ln^2(t)}{2}$$
as you expected.

Comment: Wow, nice! Thanks a lot Robert! : )  Are you cool if I reproduce this for my bachelor project?

Comment: @AfterMath Yes, no problem at all... Good luck for your project!

Comment: Thanks again :)

Comment: +1 for showing the power of symbols. Simplifying the visible form of an expression is a great help and the use of $a, b, x$ does exactly that.